# html5 multiple select import post to controller one file ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, input

I have problem. I use html5 input type file where. But when I send selected files to controller, list of HttpPostedFileBase has good count but every file is the same. Example I select files:

- 1.xml
- 2.xml
- 3.xml

List has count 3 and every of rows are 1.xml.

```
Code View form:
<form target="response" action="/test/Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" accept="text/xml" id="files" name="files[]" multiple="multiple"/><br/>
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(List<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
  Any code Here....
}
```

Comment: I will look at this post, when I find solution I delete this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpContext context)
{
  for (int files = 0; files < context.Request.Files.Count; files++)
 {
 // Code here
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write [] in name attribute you only have to give name no need of [].

```
<input type="file" accept="text/xml" id="files" name="files" multiple="multiple"/>
```

And in controller you can do this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
 foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
 {
  //Save file
 }
}
```